# Website still insecure, but everything is set up as it should be

Tags: security, ssl, web, ttl

I made website, made landing page.
Then I added TLS/SSL - Which CPanel provides.
When I type {My Website} (without any http:// or https://, just website.com) in browser, I get "This site is not secure".
When I add https://{My Website} It shows "This site is secure"

Is everything fine?

1. I cleaned Cache (Thought myb preloaded website messes with SSL)
2. I didnt add insecure links in any of code like (http://.....) just (../../)
3. I checked CPanel and it shows that my site is secured, even ran AutoSSL

P.S - Any tips in future? I want to make this website as E-Store, and i want to know what should i do more, to secure data.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your website is still supporting http & https. In your load balancer or where SSL certificate is configured, you need to force SSL. That way if someone tries to access http site, they would be redirected to https. You can do a 301 redirect for that.

Comment: Alright, in CPanel i cannot force SSL, i have only "TLS/SSL Statuss, And place where to change key bits" - But if set 301, will this work on whole website? or i will need to redirect each directory ?

Comment: 301 was the key, thanks! I thought that it wont work the way i thought.